# Functor/Applicative-like typeclass for composing (a->a) functions instead of (a->b)?

Tags: haskell

I have a type that looks like this:

```
newtype Canonical Int = Canonical Int
```

and a function

```
canonicalize :: Int  -> Canonical  Int
canonicalize =  Canonical . (`mod` 10)  -- or whatever
```

(The Canonical type may not be important, it just serves to distinguish "raw" values from "canonicalized" values.)

I'd like to create some machinery so that I can canonicalize the results of function applications.

For example: **(Edit: fixed bogus definitions)**

```
cmap :: (b->Int) -> (Canonical b) -> (Canonical Int)
cmap f (Canonical x) = canonicalize $ f x

cmap2 :: (b->c->Int) -> (Canonical b) -> (Canonical c) -> (Canonical Int)
cmap2 f (Canonical x) (Canonical y) = canonicalize $ f x y
```

That's superficially similar to Functor and Applicative, but it isn't quite, because it's too specialized: I can't actually compose functions (as required by the homomorphism laws for Functor/Applicative) unless 'b' is Int.

My goal is to use existing library functions/combinators, instead of writing my own variants like `cmap`, `cmap2`. Is that possible?  Is there a different typeclass, or a different way to structure Canonical type, to enable my goal?

I've tried other structures, like

```
newtype Canonical a = Canonical { value :: a, canonicalizer :: a -> a }
```

but that hits the same non-composability problem, because I can't translate one canonicalizer to another (I just want to use the canonicalizer of the result type, which is always `Int` (or `Integral a`)

And I can't force "specialization-only" like so, this isn't valid Haskell:

```
instance (Functor Int) (Canonical Int)
```

(and similar variations)

I also tried

```
newtype (Integral a) => Canonical a = Canonical a -- -XDatatypeContexts
instance (Integral a) => Functor Canonical where
  fmap f (Canonical x) = canonicalize  $ f x
```

but  GHC says that `DatatypeContexts` is deprecated, and a bad idea, and more severely,
I get:

```
 `Could not deduce (Integral a1) arising from a use of 'C'   
 from the context (Integral a)
 bound by the instance declaration
 [...] fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> (C a1 -> C b)
```

which I think is saying that the constraint `Integral a` can't actually be used to constrain `fmap` to `(Integral -> Integral)` the way I wish, which is sort of obvious (since `fmap` has two type variables) :-(

And of course this isn't valid Haskell either

```
instance (Integer a) => Functor Canonical where
```

**Is there a similar typeclass I could use, or am I wrong to try to use a typeclass at all for this functionality of "implicitly canonicalize the results of function calls"?**

Comment: Let's step back a bit. Are you sure the type signature `cmap2 :: (b->c->Int) -> (Canonical Int) -> (Canonical Int)` describes what you want? Because it looks pretty senseless. It also has nothing to do with `Functor`. Here's an example of a valid functor signature: `(Int -> Int) -> Canonical Int -> Canonical Int`.

Comment: My mistake, I made errors when simplifiying my more complicated type down to something to ask on SO. I've (tried to) improve the definitions, made an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're trying to achieve is available in the [mono-traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html) package, and in this case the MonoFunctor typeclass.

Comment: Ah, the magic of mono-traversable is its use of 'type family'. With that, a concrete type `Text` can be viewed as a `Foo Char`. 

Interesting, in `omap`, `Char` is then used as `Element Text`, and the signature is `(Element m -> Element m) -> m -> m`  which is not exactly `(a -> a) -> m a -> m a`. In some sense, `m` is seen as `UnElement (Element m)`, to make the type signature match `fmap`.

Comment: Need to get mono-traversable into fpcomplete ;-). http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130922-179/

Comment: It's available in the unstable package set. At the time that we created the September stable snapshot, mono-traversable wasn't stabilized enough.

Comment: Ah, yesterday I couldn't find the hamburger menu to access settings in the FPComplete IDE.  Switching to unstable works great!  https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/using-fphc/fp-haskell-center-settings-editor/fp-haskell-center-settings-page#environment

Answer (score 2):

from your type signatures this looks a bit like the `Identity` monad

```
newtype Identity a = Identity a

instance Monad Identity where
         return x = Identity x
         f >>= (Identity x)  = Identity (f x)
```

then in your example `canonicalize = return` and `cmap f x = f >>= (return x)`

hope this is helpful

### Edit

The other structure that comes to my mind is *Automorphisms* (I studied math)

so if you have

```
data Automorphisms a = AMorph (a -> a)
```

then you can have a Monoid

```
instance Monoid Automorphism where
         mempty = id
         mappend = (.)
         mconcat = foldr1 (.)
```

(I hope foldr1 is the right one)

Comment: I agree it looks a bit like `Identity`, but I think the same type-checking problem applies if I try to put `canonicalize` into the *left*-hand side of the definition. `Identity` and `Canonical` are parametric-polymorphic, but `canonicalize` is ad-hoc polymorphic at best.

Comment: can you explain that a bit - I think I am outsmarted at the moment (the ad-hoc polymorphic makes my head mushy) - maybe tomorrow I'll grok it

Comment: I mean that `Identity`  works for any type `a->a`, but `canonicalize` is implemented as `Int -> Int`

Comment: Your `Automorphisms` is `Endo` from `Data.Monoid`

Comment: @misterbee: what about just using `Identity` for everything, and only canonicalizing when necessary?  Then you could use all of Haskell's polymorphism most of the time, and you'd only require a canonicalized `Int` when absolutely necessary.  This approach could be pretty lightweight if you additionally defined an isomorphism between `Identity Int` and `Canonical Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cmap` is actually implementable via `fmap`. It's a bit strange at first, but `(->)` is just a datatype itself, actually equivalent to `Reader`. We can `fmap` over the return result.

```
cmap :: (a -> Int) -> a -> (Canonical Int)
cmap = fmap Can
```

You can create the other `cmap` variants using the same pattern

```
cmap2 :: (a -> b -> Int) -> a -> b -> (Canonical Int)
cmap2 = fmap (fmap Can)

cmap3 :: (a -> b -> c -> Int) -> a -> b -> c -> (Canonical Int)
cmap3 = fmap (fmap (fmap Can))
```

Now this usually is a bit of a strange thing to see in code, it's more common to see the less general form of `fmap` on `(->)`

```
instance Functor (r ->) where
  fmap = (.)

cmap :: (a -> Int) -> a -> (Canonical Int)
cmap = (.) Can
cmap f = Can . f

cmap2 :: (a -> b -> Int) -> a -> b -> (Canonical Int)
cmap2   = (.) ((.) Can)
cmap2   = (.) (Can .)
cmap2 f = (Can .) . f

cmap3 :: (a -> b -> c -> Int) -> a -> b -> c -> (Canonical Int)
cmap3   = (.) ((.) ((.) Can))
cmap3   = (.) ((.) (Can .))
cmap3   = (.) ((Can .) .)
cmap3 f = ((Can .) .) . f
```

Obviously this gets a little ridiculous in the higher order combinators. Pointfree style might not be the best choice.

Comment: That looks encouraging, but note that I am not simply trying to tag a value with the `Canonical` constructor. I am also trying to add a transformation : `canonicalize =  Canonical . (\`mod\` 10) `